# write an array of string into a file

Tags: c, function, file

In the program below I converted a text(array of strings) from a file to morse and now I need to write this converted text into another file, but theres a warning `lvalue required as left operand of assignment` in line `toupper(line[i]) = l[j].lettersMorse;}`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* Constants */
#define T_MORSE 8
#define Q_LETTERS 26
#define Q_NUMBERS 10
#define Q_MORSE (Q_LETTERS+Q_NUMBERS)
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 50



typedef struct{          /* needs a position to the string finisher \0               */
    char letters[5];     /* stores the letters , get it as a string , but use only the first letter */
    char lettersMorse[T_MORSE];/* stores the respective morse symbols of the letters                  */
}alphabet;
alphabet l[Q_MORSE];

char process(const char *line) {
    int j, i;
    FILE *p;
    for (i = 0; line[i]; ++i) {
        for ( j = 0; j < Q_MORSE; ++j ){      //vector for the letters and numbers in morse
         if (toupper(line[i]) == l[j].letters[0]){
            toupper(line[i]) = l[j].lettersMorse;}
        }
    }p = fopen("decod.txt", "w");
    fprintf(p,"%s",line);
}

int main(){
    int cont=0,j;
    FILE *arch;
    arch = fopen("morse.txt","r");
    if( arch == NULL ){
        printf("ERROR");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        while(fscanf(arch,"%s%s",l[cont].letters,l[cont].lettersMorse) != EOF){
            l[cont].letters[1] = '\0';                            /* eliminates unwanted characters            */
            for(j=0; j<strlen(l[cont].lettersMorse); j++){
                if(l[cont].lettersMorse[j] == '*'){               /* if an asterisk is found              */
                   l[cont].lettersMorse[j] = '\0';                /* eliminates the asterisk                   */
                   break;
                }
            }

            cont++;                                             /* point to the next position of the vector      */

        }
    }
    fclose(arch);

    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    fp = fopen("original.txt", "r");
    if (arch==NULL){
    printf("ERROR");}
    while (fscanf(fp,"%s",line) != EOF) {
    process(line);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The file "morse.txt" is:

```
A .-*
B -...*
C -.-.*
D -..*
E .*
```

etc... the 26 letters and the 10 digits

Comment: You can't assign a value to `toupper(line[i])`. Just assign to `line[i]`.

Comment: ^-- this. Eventually : `line[i] = toupper(l[j].lettersMorse);`

Comment: but now I have this warning `assignment of read-only location *(line + (sizetype)i)` and if I change the (const char *line) the warning is: `assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] -> line[i] = l[j].lettersMorse;}`

Comment: @Cid, note that `lettersMorse` is an array and must be indexed.

Comment: @lurker ^-- (forgot to mention you above)

Comment: The logic in the `process` function is not correct. You should use another array of `char`s to store the resulting morse code. Morse symbols are longer than one byte mostly, which makes it difficult to perform an in-place conversion on the same array.

Comment: @Ognum, I'm ignoring the bigger picture logic issues others have already pointed out for the moment, but just read the error or warning. It says "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast". So you are assigning a pointer type to an integer type. if this is really your intention, then you should cast it. If it is not, then you need to fix it.